# Command line based IP traffic generator

Tags: ip, network-traffic, iperf

Does anyone know of a  command line based traffic generator which can produce IP  traffic so that we cant test QOS feature on DSL modem . It would be good if we can set the dscp marking in the IP packet .

Curently we are using Iperf but we can't set the dscp marking .

Regards,
Mithun

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Packgen says it supports the DSCP that you reqaire:

http://packgen.rubyforge.org/files/README.html

Scapy is another:

http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy

here is a nice list of generators/tools:

http://www.protocoltesting.com/trgen.html

Comment: +1 for mentionning scapy because it is a great learning tool, but it may not be able to generate a fairly high amount of trafic if needed.

Comment: anything as windows executable ??

Comment: The ruby interpreter is your windows executable. You will just create a ruby script that does the packgen business then run it.

Answer (score 1):

[iperf](http://sourceforge.net/projects/iperf/) - measure network performance

Pretty much the standard tool, imo

windows exe:
http://www.noc.ucf.edu/Tools/Iperf/